# change Facebook share preview image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I have a web page that has a share button and this button shares posts that are on the page. I want to change the preview image when sharing the post. I have meta og:image and it picks up image from there but I want to change and add image as in the screen

I tried everything that saw on google but I could not do what I want

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can only do that by sharing a second URL (for example with a query string parameter), that returns a different og:image meta tag. You need to be aware that Facebook will treat those as different Open Graph objects as well then though; meaning like and share counts will be separate.

Comment: Okay, and what can be the fault of the irreplaceable measures? I specifically need 1080 1080 and when I write these sizes in og:image:width and og:image:height it cuts my picture